# check all checkboxes doesn't work , asp.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a view like below

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkall"  name="check_all"/><span>Check All</span>
 <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Selected</th>           
        <th>Name</th>         
   </tr>
    @foreach (School.Data.ViewModels.Student item in Model.StudentDetails)
    {
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelitem => item.IsChecked, new { @onclick = "studentChecked(this);", @name="checked1", @class="idrow" })  </th>  
             <th> @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Name)</th>      
        </tr>
    }

 </table>

 <script>
    $(document).on(' change', 'input[name="check_all"]', function () {
       $('.idRow').prop("checked1", this.checked);
    });
 </script>
```

I have one checkbox by the name "check_all". When I select this checkbox all checkboxes in the table must be selected. How can I do this?. 
I have seen this page http://jsfiddle.net/GW64e/, but still didn't work. please help :)

Comment: Probably you're subscribing wrong event handler. Try with `$('#checkall').on('click', function (e) { ... })` and see if that works.

Comment: I tried it, but still didn't work

Comment: `$(".idRow")` vs `@class="idrow"` - note the capitalization.

Comment: sorry, I was wrong there, but I fixed it and it still didn't work @TylerRoper

Comment: I'm actually not sure how your code is being _rendered_ (you have variables but don't use them, etc. etc)  - so go through the _rendered_ HTML and make sure your element `name`s and `id`s are what you expect.

Comment: $("#checkall").click(function () {
     $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
 });  check this one

Comment: @chaeusangchen property always be  $('.idRow').prop("checked", this.checked);

Answer (score 0):

**Below code will check all the checkbox**

```
  $("#checkall").click(function () {
        $(".idrow").attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
```

**Below code will uncheck and check 'check all' checkbox based on selection**

```
$(".idrow").click(function() {
    if (!this.checked) {
        $("#checkall").attr('checked', false);
    }
    else if ($(".idrow").length == $(".idrow:checked").length) {
        $("#checkall").attr('checked', true);
    }
});
```